# mysql - failed unable to start

Tags: mysql

I don't know why this error

Error message:

```
root@li1714-176:/data/mysql# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysqld; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-25 08:47:34 CST; 23min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3776 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysqld start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 25 08:47:32 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Mar 25 08:47:32 li1714-176 mysqld[3776]: Starting MySQL
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 mysqld[3776]: .. * The server quit without updating PID file (/data/mysql/mysql.pid).
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
```

```
Mar 25 09:31:52 li1714-176 rsyslogd[588]: file '7' write error: No space left on device [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
Mar 25 09:31:52 li1714-176 rsyslogd[588]: action 'action 2' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messa
Mar 25 09:31:52 li1714-176 rsyslogd[588]: file '7' write error: No space left on device [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
Mar 25 09:31:54 li1714-176 sshd[8551]: Failed password for invalid user mk from 170.231.57.142 port 6220 ssh2
Mar 25 09:31:54 li1714-176 sshd[8551]: Received disconnect from 170.231.57.142 port 6220:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 25 09:31:54 li1714-176 sshd[8551]: Disconnected from invalid user mk 170.231.57.142 port 6220 [preauth]
```

journalctl -u mysqld.service  error:

```
Mar 25 06:40:19 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Mar 25 06:40:19 li1714-176 mysqld[751]: Starting MySQL
Mar 25 06:40:21 li1714-176 mysqld[751]: .. * The server quit without updating PID file (/data/mysql/mysql.pid).
Mar 25 06:40:21 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 25 06:40:21 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 06:40:21 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
Mar 25 08:47:32 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Mar 25 08:47:32 li1714-176 mysqld[3776]: Starting MySQL
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 mysqld[3776]: .. * The server quit without updating PID file (/data/mysql/mysql.pid).
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 08:47:34 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
Mar 25 09:31:40 li1714-176 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Mar 25 09:31:40 li1714-176 mysqld[7625]: Starting MySQL
Mar 25 09:31:42 li1714-176 mysqld[7625]: .. * The server quit without updating PID file (/data/mysql/mysql.pid).
```

How to free up more space.

I want to start or extract the database normally

Answer (score 1):

Given rsyslog is complaining about 'No space left on device' I suspect that mysql will have the same problem. It needs space to work as well.

```
journalctl -u mysqld.service
```

to see mysql errors, though it is probably also having limited recording due to out of space.

Fix the amount of free space on your storage and make all your programs happy.

Comment: hi,I added the 'journalctl -u mysqld.service' log,how to free up more space.

Comment: `df -h` to see what filesystem is out of space. Look for things to delete there that you don't need. Don't delete mysql files or it will break. Search for general answers in unix.stackexchange.com/ and probably ask your question there with the `df -h` output, your `/etc/fstab` contents, and if you are using lvm `vgs -v; lvs -v`, and include your distro and version.